# Is there a command to get remainder of negative numbers directly in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

In python ,when we call something like that ,

```
j=-96
print(j%5) #answer will be 4.
print(j//5) #answer will be -20
```

that means python get remainder by -96=(-20)*5 + 4,Is there a way to get real remainder for negative numbers without calling something like that?

```
j=-96
print((-1)*(((-1)*j)%5)) # answer will be -1.
```

Comment: Please define your vision of *remainder* operator. Read about [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) and of course the documentation of [Python](http://python.org/)

Comment: (-86)%4=-2
(-86) mod 4 = -2
like that

Comment: Read more math, e.g. about [cyclic groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group) such as Z/nZ. Your question is not much related to Python

Comment: -(abs(x)%5)   This gives -(abs(-96)%5)=-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is good reason why `%` behaves the way it does -- see http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html

If you really want to go against this, then yes, you will need "something like that".

Here is another way that you could write it, if it's any help.

```
def mod(n, b):
    return abs(n) % b * (1 if n>=0 else -1)

print(mod(-96, 5))
```

Comment: I always find it amazing when languages don't have a sign function. But kudos for the history

Answer (score 2):

Use the absolute value function!

```
j=-96
remainder = j < 0 ? -(abs(j) % 5) : j%5
```

This will give you your desired result of -1

Wrap this in a function like this for easy use

```
mod(a,b):
    if a < 0:
        return -(abs(a) % b)
    else:
        return a%b
```

Comment: The desired result is -1, not 1

Comment: @Nick sorry, fixed it

Comment: output want to be -1 .type is negative int

Answer (score 1):

try;

```
import math
math.fmod(-96,5)
```

Comment: This returns a float. The question is about integer arithmetic.

Comment: Yes it will do. The OP seemed to want a very simple expression, but I think that they are not going to find one.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you allow negative remainders, you can get the second remainder by just subtracting the divisor from the positive remainder (they are supposed to be adjacent)

```
neg_remainder = (j%5) - 5 if j%5 else 0 # -1
```

Python follows the positive remainder convention - so the `%` operator will always give you positive remainders

Comment: As i mentioned, "direct commands" in python will always give you positive remainders. You can wrap the operation I described in a function to get what you want

Comment: You probably don't want `-5` if the `%` returns `0`. (EDIT: okay now fixed I see)

Comment: Actually, Python follows the convention that the result of the `%` will always have *the same sign as the divisor*